# SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) }

Tags: java, android, security, google-cloud-messaging

I try to get my GCM registrationId from Google.

my code:

```
String SENDER_ID = "722******53";

/**
 * Registers the application with GCM servers asynchronously.
 * <p>
 * Stores the registration ID and the app versionCode in the application's
 * shared preferences.
 */
private void registerInBackground() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String msg = "";
            try {
                if (gcm == null) {
                    gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                }
                regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                // You should send the registration ID to your server over
                // HTTP, so it
                // can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
                sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                // For this demo: we don't need to send it because the
                // device will send
                // upstream messages to a server that echo back the message
                // using the
                // 'from' address in the message.

                // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
                storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
                // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
                // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
                // exponential back-off.
            }
            return msg;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            mDisplay.append(msg + "\n");
        }
    }.execute(null, null, null);
}
```

I get an error:

```
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1800)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1772)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:480)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.b(Unknown Source)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at com.example.gcm.DemoActivity$1.doInBackground(DemoActivity.java:177)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at com.example.gcm.DemoActivity$1.doInBackground(DemoActivity.java:1)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
03-01 19:15:36.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3467):     ... 4 more
```

here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.manyexampleapp"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:name="com.zoomer.ifs.BaseApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


         <activity
            android:name="com.zoomer.ifs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
                android:launchMode="singleTop">
<!--             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>

     <!--     PUSH -->

        <!--
          WakefulBroadcastReceiver that will receive intents from GCM
          services and hand them to the custom IntentService.

          The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is necessary
          so only GCM services can send data messages for the app.
        -->
        <receiver
            android:name="com.example.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.example.gcm.GcmIntentService" />

         <activity
            android:name="com.example.gcm.DemoActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

           <!--     DB -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.db.DbActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.http.RestGetActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fb.FacebookLoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <!--
                      <intent-filter>
                                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.http.SendFeedbackActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <!--
                 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.zoomer.general.SearchNearbyOffersActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.StoresListActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.fb.ShareActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.notifications.NotificationsActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.fb2.no_use.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.zoomer.offers.OffersListActivity" >

            <!--
                 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            -->
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.http.SearchNearbyOffersActivity" >
<!--             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.example.geo.LocationService"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <receiver android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.BootReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.LocationService.LOCATION_BROAD_MSG" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Post the code that you are using to get registration id

Comment: added. thanks. can you have a look?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.manyexampleapp.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

to

```
 <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

You are getting the exception because you have not defined the required permissions

Comment: I already added this permission in both - my app and library project  - and still getting this error.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky : Sorry for the late reply. Hope you have solved it by now. If not post the error that you are getting. Also try the project which can be found here https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html along with much more detailed explanation as what needs to be done for GCM implemetation

Comment: On some android Rom,Google Play service is not installed,will encounter this issue,not the staff relating permissions

Comment: If you're using the play services plugin, the uses-permission entry will be automatically added to the manifest. To check this, you can use `File > Profile or Debug APK...` in Android Studio and inspect the manifest.  No need to add the uses-permission entry manually.

Answer (score 2):

In case the play services are installed after the app being developed,
it might happen that the `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE` permission is already given but android is still complaining about it with the same error.

In this case you must do a complete re-install of the developed app in order for this permission to work.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't only true for pre-Marshmallow devices?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check Kotlin version Compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

This specific permission is related to Google Services Framework (GSF) and is used for reading GServices.

Modify your permission use this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
```